# Hibernate vs EclipseLink

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistência, eclipse-link

Ambos os frameworks de persistência implementam a JPA.

1 - Existe diferença entre os dois?

2 - Qual o melhor em performance?

3 - Como os dois implementam a mesma especificação, depois de desenvolver uma aplicação completa é possível alterar de um framework para outro sem precisar grandes alterações no código fonte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambos os frameworks de persistência implementam a JPA.

1 - Existe diferença entre os dois?
Sim, existe diferenças.
No entanto, o senso comum entenda que o propósito é o mesmo: ambos implementam a [Especificação JPA](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1490934426_f4af9790d2dd801842e8c3988b33e9ec). 
O Hibernate nasceu sem JPA mas hoje em dia é comum acessar o Hibernate pela especificação JPA: podemos citar: Hibernate da JBoss, EclipseLink da Eclipse Foundation e o OpenJPA da Apache. Apesar do Hibernate ter originado a JPA, o EclipseLink é a implementação referencial. [[Hibernate - Frameworks ORM](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/uma-introducao-pratica-ao-jpa-com-hibernate/#14-2-java-persistence-api-e-frameworks-orm)]

---

2 - Qual o melhor em performance?
o EclipseLink fornecem camadas e recursos de cache muito mais sofisticados e exóticos, 
como armazenamento em cache isolado para suporte a banco de dados private virtual (virtual private database - vpd). E tem mais, No caso do EclipseLink, ele tem um cache de objetos compartilhados totalmente integrado, assim não só o gerenciamento de contexto de persistência local é eficiente, mas também todos os threads no mesmo servidor podem se beneficiar do conteúdo compartilhado do cache. [[Pro JPA 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430249269)]

---

3 - Como os dois implementam a mesma especificação, depois de desenvolver uma aplicação completa é possível alterar de um framework para outro sem precisar grandes alterações no código fonte?
Em teoria sim, deveria. A linguagem de consulta principal é Java Persistence Query Language (JP QL), uma linguagem de consulta independente de banco de dados que opera no modelo de entidade lógica em oposição ao modelo de dados físicos. Mas na prática vai depender do dialeto do SQL Nativo usado nas linhas de código (não é recomendado). Antes que linguagens como JP QL se tornassem padronizadas, o método mais comum para construir consultas em muitos provedores de persistência era através de uma API de programação. A estrutura de consulta no EclipseLink, por exemplo, foi a maneira mais eficaz de desbloquear verdadeiramente toda a potência de seu mecanismo de consulta.E, mesmo com o advento do JP QL, as APIs de programação ainda permaneceram em uso para dar acesso a recursos ainda não suportados pela linguagem de consulta padrão. [[Pro JPA 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430249269)]

---

Acredito que seja isso, e desculpem se de alguma forma fui tendencioso. Não foi a minha intensão.

#### Referências:

---

[[Especificação JPA](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1490934426_f4af9790d2dd801842e8c3988b33e9ec)]. Disponível em [***JSR-000338***: *Java(tm) Persistence Specification*](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/uma-introducao-pratica-ao-jpa-com-hibernate/). Acesso: 31 Mar 2017.

[[Hibernate - Frameworks ORM](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/uma-introducao-pratica-ao-jpa-com-hibernate/#14-2-java-persistence-api-e-frameworks-orm)]. Disponível em [***Apostila Java Web***: *Uma Introducao Prática ao JPA com Hibernate*](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/uma-introducao-pratica-ao-jpa-com-hibernate/#14-2-java-persistence-api-e-frameworks-orm). Acesso: 31 Mar 2017.

[[Pro JPA 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430249269)]. Disponível em [***Pro JPA 2*** - *A Definitive Guide to Mastering the Java Persistence API*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430249269). Acesso: 31 Mar 2017.

Answer (score 3):

1. sim existem diferença de comportamento entre os dois, porem apenas onde a especificação não deixa clara o que deve ser feito, segue os links para mais informações.
   http://blog.caelum.com.br/jpa-hibernate-ou-eclipselink/
   http://blog.caelum.com.br/jpa-2-curiosidades-nas-implementacoes-parte-2/
2. De modo geral o Hibernate costuma apresentar uma performance sucintamente melhor, segue o link com um comparativo.
   http://www.jpab.org/Hibernate/MySQL/server/EclipseLink/MySQL/server.html
3. No geral você deve alterar pouco código, mas comportamentos específicos de ao mudar de um para outro pode acabar te pregando algumas peças, como por exemplo o ID do Hibernete o preenchido logo apos chamar o metodos percist porem do EclipseLink apenas quando o registro for enviado para o DB.

Answer (score 2):

O Hibernate é mais parrudo, consome mais memória e por isso pode ser considerado mais pesado, mas em condições extremas é mais eficiente fazendo muito mais inserts e queries por minuto. Use-o em projetos em que você tenha um servidor robusto e os acesso simultâneos seja grande.

O Toplink e o Eclipselink são para projetos mais simples. São mais levinhos em memória e ótimos pra aprendizado de JPA pois dificilmente vai travar sua máquina, mas não aguentam o tranco que o Hibernate aguenta em momentos mais críticos em servidor de produção.

Isso não é apenas uma opinião minha baseada em experiência pessoal. Já ouvi os mesmos comentários de outros programadores e professores da pós. 
No link abaixo o autor do post fez alguns testes que corroboram essa perceção do Eclipselink e Toplink sendo menos robustos que o Hibernate:
http://terrazadearavaca.blogspot.com.br/2008/12/jpa-implementations-comparison.html

Em termos de utilização, todos usam JPA e se você não utilizar nenhuma funcionalidade específica de uma implementação, pra trocar só vai precisar mudar propriedades no xml de persistência e meia dúzia de imports.